# Asp.net web application database connection problem after uploading to plesk

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, database-connection

I have uploaded asp.net web application to server using filezilla ..after upload it only shows folders like this App data ,controllers extra..
How I can change connection strings in web config file so that my website is accessible ..
What should I change in connection strings so that my database is connected to server

Comment: Can you please show the connections strings you've used?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow!

When you upload your files to a server with FileZilla it depends on your server if your files will be treated as normal files on a server or if they are treated as a ASP.NET web application.

What kind of server are you uploading your files to? Is it prepared to run ASP.NET applications? Right now it sounds like your server does not and therefore by default just shows the files on the server.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have several requirements here.

1. The server you're talking about, is this a dedicated server where there's an IIS installed / enabled?
2. About the ConnectionString, do you have a database hosted on a server as well where you can connect to? If yes, then you need the IP address of that server and use it on the connectionstring then you can push it to Filezilla again.
3. Please take a look at these examples.

**I suggest you go through this since this is a step by step process, and it covers the basics of deployment. If you decided to deploy to Azure it will almost be the same as this.**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis

**Check this if you have a hosting already like GoDaddy**
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-host-your-Asp-Net-mvc-website-on-godaddy-server/

Answer (score 0):

For connection string, you need to ask the hosting provider that you use. Each hosting provider have their own settings. The connection string should be like:

```
<add name="connString" connectionString="Data Source=our_SQL_SERVER_ID;uid=your_DB_username;pwd=your_DB_password;Initial Catalog=your_DB_name"></add>
```